# OAuth2 Authentication for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: kotlin, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

Is there a global solution to provide an OAuth authentication for a KMM Application, like written in the common main directory?

I tried to implement it with Ktor like here: https://ktor.io/docs/oauth.html and here: https://medium.com/slickteam/ktor-and-keycloak-authentication-with-openid-ecd415d7a62e, but I always failed calling the `oauth {}` lambda, because as I understood it, it can only be called inside an extension function of `Application` and in KMM there is obviously nor Application.

Or do I have to implement an OAuth library for all natives like one for Ios and one for Android, with specific libraries for each technology?

Comment: your link is to ktor for server. on mobile side, you don't need network library to do oauth: you open oauth link with redirect url in it in the native browser, and wait redirect deeplink with response data.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ktor's implementation of OAuth is available only for the JVM target (including Android). So you have to implement it for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I've written this library for kotlin multiplatform OpenID Connect Support:

https://github.com/kalinjul/kotlin-multiplatform-oidc

It's meant for KMM with iOS and Android, but also has an iOS-only Swift Package available.
On iOS, it leverages ASWebAuthenticationSession, on Android, it uses Chrome Custom Tabs to authenticate. There's a factory to abstract the Login process, so there's little platform-specific code required in your app.

Currently only Authorization Code Flow is supported. And the library is in an early stage and not tested against many IDP's yet.